# Transparent Materials Show As White when Exporting blender 3.0

Tags: materials, export, gltf

I'm using the "Basic Glass" Sample Material from Material Library VX and trying to export a 3D Object with glass, Material, reflections, lights, and all details to be used for a web 3D object presentation as glTF 2.0 and it looks fine in blender but when I try to export it all materials show up normally but transparent ones. (other export options gave the same result as well)

here's how it looks after render, with Cycles Engine

[image]

and this is how it looks after Exporting (Using gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com)

[image]

here are my export options and file, i've also tried the other two formats (Embdded and Separate) and got the same result

[image]

i've searched everywhere for a solution and i couldn't find one, the only thing i found is that i need to have basic shader nodes that makes it easier translate outside blender (by baking the material into an image texture, that didn't work, image texture result looks black, or a weird transparent color

here are my shader nodes before baking

[image]

after baking with result Image + Model

[image]

my baking Options ( i've tried different bake types like diffuse and transmission as well and got the same result)

[image]

I've also made sure that my model UV is unwrapped

[image]

it took me effectively one day finishing this model and i've been stuck with this export issue for three days now! which was the whole point of my model i.e export for external usage please help!

Comment: You are using transmission shaders with an IOR option (not the Fresnel node), you need ray-tracing to support that. Unless you have an RTX GPU and your GLTF viewer supports it (very unlikely) this won't work. I'm also not sure what the bake is supposed to achieve...

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz i'm trying to find a replacement to having those shaders yes, but not knowing how, what i understood was that baking meant to replace all those calculations and nodes and writes them on a static image texture so that it can show it on most GLTF viewers, if i was wrong, then how can i achieve that?

Comment: The GLTF exporter does not know all shader nodes. Try using a principled shader and stay away from the transmission slider, only use alpha.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz I tried that, didn't like the looks of it, probably because I'm not very good with it, didn't try to export with it though, it worked once on a test project (still ugly) but the other times I got a similar result i.e white color, will experiment with it more and write back after I finish rendering a 360° animation around the bottle, since my target result was to take 360° shot around the object for to be viewed on a web page I might not need to export Afterall, thanks for your help

Comment: Glass is inherently hard to make look nice without refractions. But without e.g. Cycles they need to be faked, usually with a post shader. I don't think many pure gltf viewers support this, but Uniry's WebGL does to an extend.
Is there a reason why you can't render your 360° with Cycles?

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz yes, but I think I also need more tweaking in cycles as well if I want it to look as good as the VX Material, for now i managed to get the 360° shot i wanted with cycles yes so everything is working alright thanks!